# JS Object destructuring a required library line of code?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am getting an es linting error for this line of code below, saying I need to use object destructuring.

`const myTest = require('chai').myTest;`

How do I do this for requiring a library?

Answer (score 4):

Just put the library expression on the right-hand side of the assignment operator, destructuring a `require` call is no different from destructuring any object:

```
const { myTest } = require('chai');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use destructure.

```
const { myTest } = require('chai');
```